# How to enable HTML editor in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, editor

**Hey guy's** 
I want to enable HTML editor on my wordpress blog. Just because whenever i type any HTML code for any tool like Flip text or something other than it shows only HTML codes in the post. But i want to convert this into a visual. So can you help me?? 
You can see any post of my blog that is http://multipletricks.com/
Please give me suggestion fast and **Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the "Text" tab at the top right corner of the post editor pane. This allows you to add HTML. You can see the results of the HTML by returning to "Visual" mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for one of there 2 things;

1) Put your editor in "Text" modus from the upper right

2) Or install a code syntax highlight plugin to show off snippets of code from within a post

https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/